# Can't launch PhoneGap app on Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, cordova, android-virtual-device

I am getting errors when I try to run my PhoneGap hello world application. It is my first application.

```
Still no compatible AVDs with target 'Android 5.1.1': Aborting launch.
Launch canceled!
```

Comment: I think you haven't installed And 5.1.1 sdk

Comment: I installed Andrioid sdk platform 5.1.1

Comment: Are you trying to run it on an emulator? Or a mobile phone?

Comment: I run on an emulator

Comment: I got error like ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but could not find AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google.ini file in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\.android\avd